# Login to idrive using a script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, installation, windows-installer

I am trying login to Idrive using a set of 2 required credentials upon login.

1. username and password // for main account
2. username and password // for sub account

I want automate this process with a batch script, which will automatically login once installed then set the backups to run everyday at noon using the default setting folders.

So far all I am able to do is a silent install:

```
C:\>IDriveWinSetup.exe /remote /silent
```

Comment: I would suspect that you will need to perform some modifications to the new installation files, or add new configuration information immediately after installing too!

Comment: Don't post code in comments please. Instead edit your question and add the relevant code.